# get value from input box in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, there are only 2 pages- **popup.html** and **result.html**.
Both pages has same form with same id. Form contains 1 input box and one submit button.

There are 3 problems I am facing

1. I have to click on button to make it work. It do not work when I
   hit enter.
2. I am not able to change the value of variable
   `globalURL`
3. I am not able to retrieve input box value that
   present on popup.html

I am new in this and trying to solve the problems from last 2 days. Got many solution on stackoverflow and on google none were appropriate to the requirements

Please help!!

Manisfest-

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Seolyzer",
  "description": "Analyze your websites now.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["assets/js/jquery.js", "assets/js/myapp.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequestBlocking",
          "webRequest",
          "*://*.google.com/",
          "<all_urls>",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
          "https://*/*"
        ],
 "js": ["content.js"]
}
```

Popup.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>-Result</title>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/boostrap-mini.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/myapp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form class="form-inline" method="post"  id="domain1" action="result.html" target="_blank">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" required="required" name="domain" placeholder="Enter your domain here" class="form-control input-lg" id="domain inputlg" style="height:49px;font-size:larger;">
           <div class="input-group-btn" style="width:1%;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="urlbutton" style="height:49px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats">&nbsp</i>Analyze it</button>
                   </div> </div>    
               </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Result.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>-Result</title>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/boostrap-mini.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/myapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <form class="form-inline" method="post"  id="domain1" action="result.html" target="_blank">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" required="required" name="domain" placeholder="Enter your domain here" class="form-control input-lg" id="domain" style="height:49px;font-size:larger;">
       <div class="input-group-btn" style="width:1%;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="urlbutton" style="height:49px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats">&nbsp</i>Analyze it</button>
               </div> </div>    
           </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Myapp.js

```
var globalURL="google.com"

      $(function(){
          $('#urlbutton').click(function(){
        var urll="facebook.com";
globalURL= urll;
        if(urll)
        {

         console.log("New "+ urll); 
        }
        else
        {
          console.log("no");

          }

        })})
console.log(globalURL);
```

Comment: i don't understand when results page should be shown, but anyway different parts of extension can communicate only via sending messages: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging

Comment: @PavelAgarkov when anybody click on button (either on both pages), then the result should  show on result.php